# android fragment tablelayout

Tags: android, fragment

Looking for a example of using a fragment code to build multiple rows in a table where the layout of each row is: example to create 3 rows.

Subject.........................    button
Title ....................................
..........................................

Subject.........................    button
Title ....................................
..........................................

Subject.........................    button
Title ....................................
..........................................

Comment: It should beSubject.........................    button
Title ....................................
..........................................

Comment: Subject.........................    button  (LINE1
Title .................................... LINE2
.......................................... LINE4

Comment: edit instead of writing comments

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is

1. Adapter
2. RecyclerView
3. Item Layout